# How to configure the Logging using log4j in websphere liberty server?

Tags: java, log4j, websphere, websphere-liberty

I tried to configure the logging in liberty profile but not getting the logs getting printed in my log file. I did the followings
1.In server.xml

```
<logging maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10" traceFileName="trace.log" traceSpecification="*com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontiner*=all:com.ibm.ws.classloader.*=all:HTTPChannel=all:app.manager*=all:"/>
<logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" traceFormat="ADVANCED"/>
```

2.my log4j.property file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C://log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Even after this I am not able to see any logs.

Please specify the log4j.properties file and the configurations need to get logging done in liberty server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liberty does not use Log4j for internal logging and tracing. You will find server log files in the `LIBERTY_INSTALL\usr\servers\serverName\logs` directory.

For more information about logging see [Liberty profile: Logging and Trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SS7K4U_8.5.5%2F1-17-0-0&lang=en)

Comment: Thanks Gas, I found the server logs are getting places correctly in LIBERTY_INSTALL\usr\servers\serverName\logs but when I log from my java code those are not getting appended or the different file is not being created. Can you please tell which Logger should I use?

Comment: @user3860615 If you are at start of the development, the easiest would be just to use JUL logger. It is integrated in Liberty logging, so you will be able to change the logging level via `<logging>` element. If you prefer log4j check this link how to put log4j.properties in the classpath - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/19024/how-to-add-log4jproperties-to-liberty-classpath/